# Redirect output with file properties info

Tags: batch-file

I've batch script that will copy file from one folder to another folder and generate log. How can I modify it so that in the log it can display file size and date modified information ?

```
@echo off

set path=c:\WINDOWS\system32;

echo Copying started at %date% %time%>>CopyXR222.log

set  source=D:\Testing1

set  dest=D:\Testing2

echo %source%
echo %dest%


del %dest%\*.* /q

xcopy %source%\222*.csv %dest%\  /s /e  >>CopyXR222.log

echo Copying finished at %date% %time%>>CopyXR222.log

echo Completed Successfully at %date% %time%>>CopyXR222.log

echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------- >>CopyXR222.log

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

```
robocopy "%source%" "%dest%" *.csv /s /ts /np /njh /njs /nc /ndl /log+:CopyXR222.log /tee
```

- `/s` copies subdirectories, you can add `/e` to also copy all empty directories
- `/ts` adds timestamp
- `/np /njh /njs /nc /ndl` hides `0-100%` progress, header and summary, "class", directory list
- `/log+:CopyXR222.log /tee` appends to the log file and also displays the progress in the console